# Does bitcoin-core software/client connects with only same version number nodes?

Tags: nodes, connection, peer-discovery, fallback-nodes

i am trying to connect to maximum number of `nodes`.

i noticed there are many `receive version message` in `debug.log` file

so i have question, does the bitcoin-core connects to only those having either same `version number` or in short range of `version message` of our bitcoin's `version message` ?

or does it connects to all and any `nodes` which completes the `handshake` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see from the Debug Window ("Peers" tab) that the Bitcoin Core client connects with multiple clients not only with different versions but different implementations.

So to answer your question: No.

[image: Bitcoin Core peer list]

Comment: thanks, i am using non gui version, so didnt noticed it.

Comment: The `getpeerinfo` RPC call will tell you the same thing.